# Visual Studio Code: Error: Git Failed to execute

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code (version: 1.12.1) and after that I installed Git (version: 2.13.0.windows.1) on Windows 10 machine.
 Then:

1. I created an Asp.Net project (img 1)
2. I open it in VS Code, went to Source Control and clicked Initialize Repository (img 2)
3. I tried to commit changes (img 3).
4. And I saw this error message (img 4).
5. Then I made sure that git was the provider (img 5)
6. I went to the settings.json and override the git Path (img 6), by default it was set to null.
   But it doesn't solve the problem. I created another app from scratch and the same error message is shown.

[Click here to see the screenshots, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Vd3.png)

**Here is the Git Log Output:**

```
Using git 2.13.0.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

git init
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :../../AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :../../AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
git add -A -- .
git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - --all

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'COMPAQ@PREPARA12.(none)')

git config --get-all user.name
git show :../../AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :../../AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'COMPAQ@PREPARA12.(none)')

git config --get-all user.name
git show :../../AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :../../AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
git fetch
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

git fetch
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

git fetch
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

git fetch
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

git fetch
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'COMPAQ@PREPARA12.(none)')

git config --get-all user.name
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
```

Comment: Start by configuring your email and name using ``git config`` as suggested in the log

Comment: Thank you very much! He heh. I am new to using Git, and I had fear of log outputs, but when I read what you said I understood that is very simple. Next time I'll read the logs without fear! Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Does it work as it should now?

Comment: Yes! I set the user.email and user.name as global and now even when I create a new project I don't get that message error again.

Comment: If I decide to change the email and name can I run this commands again, whether as global or just for a specific project (omitting --global)? In this case, it will override those values, right?
 In the new project's folder, I ran: git config user.name "Lucas". Are there any commands that show me the current values for email and name?
 Anyway, thanks for helping. You held a lot!

Comment: Nice.. first you rejected my edit which added proper code formatting in your question and then edited likewise

Comment: Hi, Picard! Sorry for that, but it seems good right now. If you want, you can ask me another edition. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

From above comments:

Read the log outputs from Git. Configure your user email and user name. One way to do that is to open command prompt.  Then navigate to your folder using `cd FILEPATH`.  Then configure your user email and user name.  It can be configured globally or only within the current repo.  Configure globally with

```
git config --global user.email "youremailaddress@example.com"
```

then

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: Relevant issue from github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57222#issuecomment-417216329